# Get type from typeguard's type predicate

Tags: typescript, typeguards

Typically, a typeguard's type is defined as such:

```
(value: unknown) => value is Type
```

Where the highlighted part is called a *type predicate* by the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates):

```
(value: unknown) => **value is Type**
```

Going even forward, we could say (I don't know how, if even, the docs defines this) that the `value` is the typeguard's *parameter*, `is` is a TypeScript binary *operator*/*keyword* for defining type predicates and `Type` is the type the typeguard actually guarantee, *the guaranteed type*.
Since we use typeguards to guarantee a value's type, we could say that `Type` is the most interesting part of the definition.

Being such, is it possible to extract `Type` from the type definition of a typeguard? How?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
type Type = typeof typeguard; // (value: unknown) => value is Type
type TypePredicate = TypePredicateOf<Type>; // value is Type
type GuaranteedType = IsOf<TypePredicate>; // Type
```

Where `GuaranteedType` is the desired result.

---

Googling around, I've only found answers about [generic typeguards](https://dev.to/krumpet/generic-type-guard-in-typescript-258l) type definitions, but did not get how to get the `Type` part from it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) with the `infer` keyword to extract the guarded type from a type guard signature.  Something like:

```
type GuardedType<T> = T extends (x: any) => x is infer U ? U : never;
```

And given some user-defined type guards:

```
function isString(x: any): x is string {
  return typeof x === "string";
}

interface Foo {
  a: string;
}

function isFoo(x: any): x is Foo {
  return "a" in x && typeof x.a === "string"
}
```

You can see that it works as advertised:

```
type S = GuardedType<typeof isString>; // string
type F = GuardedType<typeof isFoo>; // Foo
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA4grgQwE4BMIoCrggHgwPigF4oMoIAPYCAOxQGcoAKCgLigRpAEpjCKoAS0aCaAMwhIoAVSgB+GVHY0IAN0kBuAFBaxcGgGNgggPY0h9AMrAkogOYt2nHuwHCo9G-agBvLVCgkCGA4JHNQSBMxKAEiOKgAIk9bGjsE7QBffy1RaiQxBANoADETE19-DnZk+0zdfSNTc2FSk0cOLm5XCyhWioCgkLDEhAShcwEAMkmoCIgomIA6BGJ4pK9UhK0srTmoS2JYRFR0LEgcOYXhaxS7fA0oAHpHjw27Xexew-hkNExsC7YK70Vr3J4vVpAA)